# If $φ:\mathbb R^d→ℂ∖\{0\}$ is continuous and $\varphi(0)=1$, then there is an unique continuous $f:\mathbb R^d→ℂ$ with $f(0)=0$ and $\varphi=e^f$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

It's been a long time, since I thought about complex analysis, so please bear with me, if this is a rather trivial question.

I've read that if $\varphi:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is continuous and $\varphi(0)=1$, then there is an unique continuous $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb C$ with $f(0)=0$ and $\varphi=e^f$. How can we prove that?

I vaguely remember branches of the complex logarithm from complex analysis, but I don't know whether or not this concept is needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}^d$ is simply connected, it suffices to note that $(\mathbb{C},e^z)$ is a covering (actually the universal covering) of $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Once you've done that, the result follows from the [lifting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties).

One does not need it to prove uniqueness though: it suffices to note that given two different functions $f_1,f_2$ such that $\varphi=e^{f_1}=e^{f_2}; f_1(0)=f_2(0)=0$, then $f_1-f_2\in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$, which is discrete, and since $f_1-f_2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (connected) it must be constant and thus $0$

Comment: To be honest, I cannot follow your proof. However, I've seen that some authors denote the $f$ in the question by $\log\varphi$ and call it the "distinguished logarithm" of $\varphi$ ... Maybe I'm missing the crucial point, but isn't the notation $\log\varphi(x)$ easily be confused with the complex logarithm of the complex number $\varphi(x)$?

Comment: What you gave is just a local definition, i.e. it does not define the function, nor it actually gives you an explicit value (since the logarithm is multivalued)

Comment: The difficulty lies in "choosing the correct values", that is in defining a continuous logarithm. Note that it is not possible to find (I think, I may be wrong) a completely non-topological proof, as the simple connectedness is fundamental to the result.

Comment: What happens if we replace $\mathbb R^d$ by the dual $E'$ of a general $\mathbb R$-Banach space? Can we still show the existence of a unique continuous $f:E'\to\mathbb C$? Maybe assuming separability?

Comment: A Banach space is simply connected, so the same proof works

Comment: Is the only reason why we can't define $f:=\ln\left|\varphi\right|+{\rm i}\operatorname{Arg}\varphi$ that $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\ni z\mapsto\operatorname{Arg}z$ is not continuous?